# pdftotext doesn't give the same result in python3 script and shell

Tags: python-3.x, pdftotext

i try to use pdftotext and when i use it in my shell with my command:
"pdftotext pdf1" it gives me:

```
Révision : 0 1
Page : 1 / 1

Test Synapture
PJK

Spécification

Document n°
PJLTest 00 PJT SPC 0201 01

25 Rue Marguerite
69100 Villeurbanne
etc..
```

but when i use it in a simple script

```
    with open(file, "rb") as f:
        pdf = pdftotext.PDF(f)
        text = "\n\n".join(pdf)
    print(text)
```

it gives me :

```
                                                                         PJLTest 00 PJT SPC 0201
                                                                                       Révision : 0 1
                                Test Synapture                                            Page : 1 / 1
PJK
                                                            Spécification
                                                                Document n°
                         PJLTest 00 PJT SPC 0201 01
                                                                                25 Rue Marguerite
                                                                               69100 Villeurbanne
                                           Tel : +33 (0)4 78.94.51.20 / Fax : +33 (0)4 78.94.51.21
  01   BPE 16/09/2015     Première édition            P. NOM1             P. NOM2            P. NOM3
 REV. ETAT   DATE     OBJET DE LA REVISION         REDACTION         VERIFICATION        APPROBATION
```

I searched on the documentation but i found nothing.

Thanks for you help!